# Security tool scan issue, Found reliance on default encoding: new String(byte[])

Tags: java, coverity

I'm getting the "Found reliance on default encoding: new String(byte[])" for the following piece of code

```
InitAuth (Auth auth) {
        String jsonString =String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(token.split(".")[1]));
        context = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
}
```

I've found solutions suggesting to use the string constructor in this format

```
new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

But the problem is, in my code if I use a second parameter, It'll turn into this signature

```
new String(string, string)
```

And as you know this constructor is not defined for **new String()** . So can someone suggest how to resolve issue. Also please add if using **Base64.getMimeDecoder()** makes sense here.

Comment: What do you mean by "in my code if I use a second parameter, It'll turn into this signature"?  That doesn't make sense.  The suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String payloadUTF8 = new String(jsonString.getBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
context = JsonPath.parse(payloadUTF8);
```

In order to call that `String` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)), the first parameter must be a `byte[]`. Pass the result of `.getBytes()` as first parameter and then you can set `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` as the second one.

[image]

Comment: the first param in my question was already coming out in bytes[] format, but if we have a string as a first param then this will work